# Deterministic and secure random number generator in C#

Tags: c#, random, cryptography

The `RandomNumberGenerator` class does not take a seed value but the `Random` class does.

As far as I understand, the `Random` class is not considered a good choice for producing entropy for security.

I need to pass in the same seed material and always get the same sequence of random numbers returned.

How can I do that in .NET 6.0?

Comment: Part of the appeal of cryptographically strong random values is that it's very hard to find out the starting seed. Part of why `Random` is weak for security is because it has a predictable seed.

Comment: Is the dupe target satisfactory? If you only really need reproducibility for testing then it should be.